# Multilanguage BBD Scheme

Tags: java, database, postgresql, lucene, liferay

I am thinking about create a **database** of books (books is formed by one or two images and some texts and numbers). I want make this  data available in multilanguage (`MULTI5-EUR` from start) and the quantity of the items could be **27000** (**25000** are translated approximatelly)

Reading a little, I see a lot of disccording about the ways to create this, the most interesting idea that I found is this:

- One unique table books and **various tables for each translatable text** (text, description.. references by a ID for each language, example) this make mi books table very big.

> ```
> Books
> ID | TITLE_ES | TITLE_EN | ..
> ```

- One unique table with common data (non translatable) and **"metadata" table**, with a **relation with a culture table**. (Culture table also will have relations with Genres, editions_name..)

> ```
> Books
> -----------
> ID | EDITION_ID | DATE | AUTHOR | GENRE_ID | METADATA_ID |...
>
> Metadata
> -----------
> ID | TITLE | DESCRIPTION | SUMMARY | CULTURE_ID ...
>
> Cultures
> ---------
> ID | CULTURE
> ```

The idea is that these books have a lot of properties what you can use to search (author, editorial, isbn, date, sells, ..) and **I want make this  as efficiently as possible.**

I will hope start a instructive disscussion about this topics, we are speaking about 30k of registers, with a grow from 500 per year aprox.. There arent a big quantity of data, no?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention Liferay in your tags, you've omitted another option: Utilizing ServiceBuilder you can easily translate individual columns just by declaring them translatable. The result will be stored as xml in the respective database columns - something that send shivers down the spine of a database normalization guy. However, it's not all bad:

Thinking of database reports with storage done this way typically sucks: Reporting tools don't know how to extract the correct language from some XML content. However, dealing with classic reports on translated key-value pairs from foreign key relationships sucks as well. Those reports won't be easy to write and quite bad in maintenance. Do you foresee that you'll use classic reporting tools? Factor this into your decision.

You mention "as efficient as possible". What's efficiency? *Efficient to write* the software? ServiceBuilder wins. *Efficient to maintain* the software? ServiceBuilder wins. *Efficient to filter* by a translated name? The database filtering mechanism for non-XML content will win. Looking up titles in a *full text index*? (you have tagged lucene in your question): It doesn't make a difference how the data is stored.

After all these thoughts there is no correct answer for this question and it most likely just causes opinionated discussions - it is probably a bad fit for stackoverflow based on the criteria for questions here. Anyway, I hope it helps, but I'd rather expect the question to be closed due to its discussion character.

Ask for DB-centric opinions and you'll get normalization thrown at you. Ask Software centric opinions and you will try to maximize the maintainability of the written code. Pick the situation that you find yourself in most likely and go with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly you should follow the rules of the [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), so all decisions has been made by people who are much more intelligen than we all in stackoverflow.

[image: This may help]

But, any abstraction of the database should be made by the database itself (using views for example). This is the standard decision in databases for abstractions.

From Wikipedia:

> The conceptual view provides a level of indirection between internal and external. On one hand it provides a common view of the database, independent of different external view structures, and on the other hand it abstracts away details of how the data is stored or managed (internal level).

Actually there is a problem: How to versionize the modifications of the database in a cvs/svn/git? Often the structural-update-querys are stored in .sql-files in the cvs/svn/git.